# != symbol query in C language

Tags: c, operators

```
int x = 15 ;
printf ( "\n%d \t %d \t %d", x != 15, x = 20, x < 30 ) ;
```

The output of the code is 1 20 1 but I assume it should be 0 20 1 since 15 == 15...

I am facing a problem with the "x != 15" part

Comment: It should be x==20 not x=20. This causes your x variable to change from 15 and actually make that answer make sense.

Comment: Your 3rd argument to `printf` is `x = 20`, which assigns `x` to 20. C makes no guarantee as to the order the arguments are evaluated, so `x = 20` could be evaluated before `x != 15`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, most lists of arguments are processed from the right to the left under most C / C++ compilers, even though the specification makes no statement about the *required* order of evaluation.

With such an understanding of how *many* compilers work, your list of arguments would be evaluated like so

```
printf ( "\n%d \t %d \t %d", x != 15, x = 20, x < 30 ) ;
```

evaluates (possibly) in the order of

```
x < 30  => 1
x = 20 (assigns x to 20, returning 20) => 20
x != 15 => 1 (because x is now 20)
```

If this evaluation order holds for your compiler, then rearranging the arguments like so

```
printf ( "\n%d \t %d \t %d", x < 30, x = 20, x != 15 ) ;
```

should yeild

```
1 20 0
```

because the comparison `x != 15` will occur before `x` is reassigned to 20.

The lesson of this exercise is to generally avoid assignments in list constructs (things that look like "a, b, c, d") or *at least* not to read assigned variables within the same list construct, as you cannot be assured of right to left or left to right evaluation (it's compiler dependent).

Comment: To be blunt, the behavior is *undefined*, and the results *will* vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: @JohnBode I thought I made that clear, but most compilers being implemented using LR type parsers lead to efficient (and therefore selected) right to left list handling.  If it wasn't clear that order of evaluation could not be assured, thank you for making it even more apparent.

Answer (score 7):

You're assigning a new value to x with `x = 20`.

You can't assume any specific order to these operations in the argument list to a function call.

Comment: I don't think he intended that at all. It doesn't look like he was surprised by the 20 in the output. I think he's only surprised that `x != 15` is evaluated after the assignment.

Comment: @sepp2k so it is, I read the question and the expected output more carefully and edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from unspecified behaviour: the order in which the expressions are executed is not mandated by the Standard to be left-to-right.
Try this instead

```
int x = 15 ;
int result1 = (x != 15);
int result2 = (x = 20);
int result3 = (x < 30);
printf ( "\n%d \t %d \t %d", result1, result2, result3 ) ;
```